# Trying to send an email with photo attachment but just getting random text

Tags: php, email, attachment, photo

I have edited this script to work with what I need it for, it still sends like it should - although all I'm getting is the "Body" `$message` and then a whole lot of random letters which go on forever...

I have no idea what I may be doing wrong, but there are a few things you should know...

`$photo` is something like: `SOTT_photos/Plymouth/290416/unio/a290416789.JPG`
So I cannot get just the image name, which is why I have used `Myphoto.jpg` although I can't see that causing this kind of error?

Photos can also be JPG, jpg, PNG, png etc... So I need something to consider all those image types which may be capitalized or not.

```
$subject = 'My SmileontheTiles Photo!';
$from = 'info@SmileontheTiles.com';
$body = $message;
$photoPath = $photo;
$photoName = 'Myphoto.jpg';
$filetype = 'image/JPG';

    $bound_text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));;
    $bound = "--" . $bound_text . "\r\n";
    $bound_last = "--" . $bound_text . "--\r\n";

    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n"
    . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

    $message =  "Sorry, your client doesn't support MIME types.\r\n"
    . $bound;

    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    . $body
    . $bound;

    $file = file_get_contents($photoPath);

    $message .= "Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    . "Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
    . $bound_last;

    mail($emails, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I can't see what might be going wrong here but maybe somebody else can help me out?

P.S - I know extra Headers are now a security risk, although I'm not sure how to compensate for that?

Comment: PHP mailer FTW https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Pro-tip, don't do it yourself. Get a library like mentioned above and get some sleep.

Comment: Why don't you send an html email? all you would then have to do is `<img src='http://www.example.com/image.png'>` and your image will appear, not to mention that it will be a  million times easier to format the email.

Comment: @Webeng There is an option to send as HTML email with photo embed although it would be nice to provide an attachment option.

Comment: @Snappysites I have modified my link in my answer, now it directs to the exact example with the functions for attaching files

Comment: http://swiftmailer.org/. is a link to a library that may help. Also if you want to reinvent the wheel, you can check out this example in the php documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#Hcom113161